# HTML5 Audio Tag Wav File Not Loading/Playing

Tags: asp.net, iis, uri

I am attempting to load an audio tag with a wav file using src="\\server\path\call.wav" but the file does not show as loaded and the player controls don't work. I am assuming this is an issue with using a Windows network path. If I copy/paste the path of the WAV file into my browser, it does load and play so I don't think it's an access permission issue. The HTML is below. The application generating this code is asp.net based, running on IIS on Windows 10. What am I missing here?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head><title>Call Player</title></head>
    <body>
        <h1>Call Player</h1>
        <span id="CallContent"><div>Call Time: 2019-12-12 15:52:23</div><audio controls><source src="\\server\share\call.wav" type="audio/wav"></audio></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: We have call recordings stored on a network path. I tried entering the UNC path into the src, but Chrome won't load it, saying it's a local resource. I also tried creating a virtual directory within my web application to the server and using that as the path, but it's asking for a login when going that route, and no matter what login I use it won't connect.

Comment: Sorry I misread your question, you seem to understand where is the issue, and I don't know nothing about asp.net and IIS. So this has nothing to do with [html5-audio], it's simply that your path is not a valid URI, sot the fetch doesn't occur, the same would be true for any resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with the application and application pool setup. I had to change the Identity of the application pool to Local System and then set the site and application up to use Windows Authentication.